# Forwarding domain and masking url

Tags: wordpress, dns, responsive, forwarding

I have website on wordpress with responsive theme. It is located on my server hosted by apache. Everything works well when I access site with IP address.
The problem is when i try forward my domain to this address.

I have two options on my domain control panel:

Forward domain.com on IP address `http://111.111.11.11:8080/website`
Result:
When i type domain.com in browser i see domain.com url but site doesnt load corectly on smartphones

Forward 301 domain.com on IP address `http://111.111.11.11:8080/website`
Result:
Type domain.com, sites loads corectly on mobiles but in url i see `http://111.111.11.11:8080/website` but i want to see domain.com

I know that in the first case the problem is that domain forwarding adds iframe to site and that is why the responsive wiev doesn't load.

I want to use 301 forwarding and mask url with domain.com. How i can achieve on wordpress.